# How to transfer wrapped DOT from Astar to Polkadot using XCM

Tags: xcm, assets, astar, transfer

How do you tranfer wrapped DOT (AssetId: `340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455`) on Astar/Shiden to Polkadot/Kusama using XCM?

Following this [guide](https://docs.astar.network/docs/learn/interoperability/xcm/building-with-xcm/native-transactions/#in-practise) from Astar XCM documentation, this demonstrates how to transfer DOT from Kusama to Shiden (mapped to wrapped DOT) using the XCM instruction `limited_reserve_transfer_asset`.

What is the equivalent XCM instruction to perform the transfer in the other direction?

I have attempted to execute the following XCM instruction using [chopsticks](https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/chopsticks), but failed with "Failed to transfer Asset".

```rust
let message = Xcm(vec![
  DescendOrigin,
  TransferWithdrawAsset {
    assets: (Here, amount).into(),
    dest: MultiLocation::parent(),
    xcm: Xcm(vec![
        DepositAsset {
          assets: All.into(),
          beneficiary: AccountId32 { 
              id: contract_pub_key
              network: None 
          }.into(),
        },
      ]),
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To transfer DOT back to Polkadot, you can use `orml-xtokens` pallet in Astar:

[image]

Comment: What is are the underlying XCM program I would need to construct without using `xtokens`? I need to know the exact list of XCM instructions which is executed to accomplish this transfer of wrapped DOT to Polkadot.

Comment: Please refer to `orml-xtoken` source code here, which is the case for transferring to the reserve chain. It applies to DOT transfer to Polkadot: https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/b3694e631df7f1ca16b1973122937753fcdee9d4/xtokens/src/lib.rs#L696-L714